# How can we read a json file as json object in golang

Tags: json, go, file-read

I have a JSON file stored on the local machine. I need to read it in a variable and loop through it to fetch the JSON object values. If I use the Marshal command after reading the file using the ioutil.Readfile method, it gives some numbers as an output. These are my few failed attempts,

Attempt 1:

```
plan, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filename) // filename is the JSON file to read
var data interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(plan, data)
if err != nil {
        log.Error("Cannot unmarshal the json ", err)
      }
fmt.Println(data)
```

It gave me following error,

```
time="2016-12-13T22:13:05-08:00" level=error msg="Cannot unmarshal the json json: Unmarshal(nil)"
<nil>
```

Attempt 2: I tried to store the JSON values in a struct and then using MarshalIndent

```
generatePlan, _ := json.MarshalIndent(plan, "", " ") // plan is a pointer to a struct
fmt.Println(string(generatePlan))
```

It give me the output as string. But if I cast the output to string then I won't be able to loop it as JSON object.

How can we read a JSON file as JSON object in golang?  Is it possible to do that?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The value to be populated by `json.Unmarshal` needs to be a pointer.

From [GoDoc](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) :

> Unmarshal parses the JSON-encoded data and stores the result in the value **pointed** to by v.

So you need to do the following :

```
plan, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
var data interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(plan, &data)
```

Your error (Unmarshal(nil)) indicates that there was some problem in reading the file , please check the error returned by `ioutil.ReadFile`

---

Also please note that when using an empty interface in unmarshal, you would need to use [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) to get the underlying values as go primitive types.

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of
>   these in the interface value:
>
> ```
> bool, for JSON booleans
> float64, for JSON numbers
> string, for JSON strings
> []interface{}, for JSON arrays
> map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
> nil for JSON null
> ```

It is always a much better approach to use a concrete structure to populate your json using `Unmarshal`.

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking at this in 2022, the `ioutil` package has been deprecated. You can still use it but you'll get annoying errors.

Instead you can use the os package.

```golang
someStruct := SomeStruct{}  // Read errors caught by unmarshal
fileBytes, _ := os.ReadFile(filename)   
err := json.Unmarshal(fileBytes, spec)
```

Note, I'm specifically ignoring the error from `os.ReadFile` since it will also cause an error in `json.Unmarshal` for the sake of the example.

Comment: Thank you for this update and clarification! I am coming to golang from python and was about to go down a rabbit hole on the use of os and ioutil package differences.

Comment: Great Answer I was just wondering, what does `err := json.Unmarshal(fileBytes, spec) ` the `spec` do? Sorry, I'm new to GoLang and getting used to the language.

Comment: @Jason from what i can gather from the source material and other comments, that should be the struct you're unmarshalling the json into.

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of generics, this has become a pretty useful snippet.

```
func LoadJSON[T any](filename string) (T, error) {
    var data T
    fileData, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return data, err
    }
    return data, json.Unmarshal(fileData, &data)
}
```